# mongodb get object inside array that contains property

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongodb table, that contains a fixture of a soccer tournament, so every matchweek looks like this:

```
 "number": 1,
 "games" : [
            {
                    "estadio" : "G C",
                    "arbitro" : "M",
                    "resultado" : "vs",
                    "editor" : "Pepe",
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5af0889e14553f0788bc9db8"),
                    "equipo_local" : "Las Palmas",
                    "equipo_visitante" : "Villareal",
                    "fecha" : "10/05/2018",
                    "horario" : "16:00",
                    "hora" : "12:12"
            },
            {
                    "estadio" : "Ciudad de Valencia",
                    "arbitro" : "A Confirmar",
                    "resultado" : "vs",
                    "editor" : "No Asignado",
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5af0889e14553f0788bc9db7"),
                    "equipo_local" : "Levante",
                    "equipo_visitante" : "Deportivo",
                    "fecha" : "28/01/2019",
                    "horario" : "18:00"
            },
            ..
          ]
```

And I want to find all the objects inside "games" of every matchweek that contains "editor" : "pepe",

I've tried something like this

```
db.fechas.find({"games.editor": "Pepe"})
```

But that is showing every "games" array that contains an object with "editor": "Pepe", and I want just that specific object, not the whole array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find` method checks whether your nested array contains any document matching your condition and returns entire document.

You need aggregation framework's [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) operator to get a subset of your array, try:

```
db.fechas.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            games: {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$games",
                    as: "game",
                    cond: {
                        $eq: [ "$$game.editor", "Pepe" ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            $expr: {
                $gt: [ { $size: "$games" }, 0 ]
            }
        }
    }
])
```

EDIT: to remove the documents where `games` array is empty you can use `$match` stage specifying condition as expression ([$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/index.html)) checking array [$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/index.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that works fine, but just one issue, it is still showing the matchweeks that don't have any game with that editor, but they have "games" empty, is there any way to avoid getting those matchweeks as a result?

Comment: @Iván sure, you can add next pipeline stage, check my modified answer

Comment: Worked perfectly! You are awesome :)